# Implement shared Flowable in RxKotlin with dynamic parameters

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

Nothing I've tried seems to solve my problem.

I have three buttons with with onClick behavior. Each of these buttons calls the same method `launchActivity` but with different parameters. `launchActivity` does some IO with the variables received from the `onClick` methods and then returns an intent. I would like to be able to implement a RxKotlin/Java Flowable to handle backpressure collectively across the three onClick methods so that I can implement `BackpressureStrategy.DROP`. So if `onClick1` was initiated `onClick2` would be dropped if initated while `launchActivity` was still processing `onClick1` on the `io()` thread.

```
class ActivityLauncher {
  fun onClick1() {
    val intent = launchActivity(inFile1, outFile1)
    startActivity(intent)
  }

  fun onClick2() {
    val intent = launchActivity(inFile2, outFile2)
    startActivity(intent)
  }

  fun onClick3() {
    val intent = launchActivity(inFile3, outFile3)
    startActivity(intent)
  }

  fun launchActivity(in: File, out: File): Intent {
    // do IO with in and out files and create an intent
    return intent
  }
}
```

If I was to implement this as say a Single, I'd implement the `onClick` methods somewhat like:

```
fun onClick() {
  Single.fromCallable(launchActivity(inFile, outFile)
      .observeOn(scheduler.io())
      .subscribeOn(scheduler.ui())
      .subscribe { i -> startActivity(i) }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to call `launchActivity` from a shared Flowable that is accessible to all three `onClick` methods while still allowing them to pass in their unique `inFile` and `outFile` variables and enforcing backpressure.

The basic criteria is:

- Ensure `launchActivity` is run on the `io()` thread
- Pass the unique arguments from each of the `onClick` methods to `launchActivity` each time `onClick[#]` is run.
- `BackpressureStrategy.DROP` is used to ensure only the first click in a series is processed in `launchActivity`
- The resulting `intent` from `launchActivity` is passed to `startActivity`

How do I implement a Flowable to allow this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really need to be done in a reactive way, seems like you're using it because of the convenience of threading - nothing wrong with that, however it brings complications when you try and model your situation using Rx.

`Single` is the correct operator to use - you only want 1 emission (`BackpressureStrategy.DROP` in a `Flowable` will still emit items of downstream if they can keep up).  You just need to make your buttons `isClickable = false` at the start of your `onClick()`, and set then back to `isClickable = true` - something like :

```
Single.fromCallable { launchActivity(inFile, outFile) }
       .doOnSubscribe { disableButtonsFunction() }
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .doFinally { enableButtonsFucntion() }
       .subscribe { i -> startActivity(i) }
```